# How to reverse a string that contains Hebrew letters and numbers?

Tags: c#

i have an hebrew string that i need to reverse.

```
"שורה שלמה בעברית 3/8" וגם נושא חדש בסוגריים (הנושא) וגם מספר בסוגריים (25) וגם נקודה בסוף משפט."
```

i used this function to reverse it

```
public static string Reverse(string s)
{
    char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(charArray);
    return new string(charArray);
}
```

the output is:

```
".טפשמ ףוסב הדוקנ םגו )52( םיירגוסב רפסמ םגו )אשונה( םיירגוסב שדח אשונ םגו \"8/3 תירבעב המלש הרוש"
```

as you can see the words in hebrew where reverse successfully but the numbers and () are reversed.

Comment: The output is exactly what you would expect from that function. What output do you want to produce? And have you tried to read up about RTL support in your UI components? Because, in fact, you don't want to reverse the string - you want to display the hebrew words in their right-to-left direction!

Comment: the output is for a legacy app

Comment: Long long time ago there used to be a program called [Ctrl-CC](http://www.evrit.co.il/cc/cc-main.htm) which used to be able to copy reversed Hebrew from web pages (I'm talking mid-90s). I used it to copy Hebrew from AS-400 terminals (which was reversed), and paste it back. The C source code for Ctrl-CC is available in the link - bottom line, I don't think there's an "easy" solution, you'll need to handle "special" cases (parentheses, quotes) yourself...

Answer (score 2):

```
 static public string ReverseOnlyHebrew(string str)
    {
        string[] arrSplit;
        if (str != null && str != "")
        {
            arrSplit = Regex.Split(str, "( )|([א-ת]+)");
            str = "";
            int arrlenth = arrSplit.Length - 1;
            for (int i = arrlenth; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (arrSplit[i] == " ")
                {
                    str += " ";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (arrSplit[i] != "")
                    {
                        int outInt;
                        if (int.TryParse(arrSplit[i], out outInt))
                        {
                            str += Convert.ToInt32(arrSplit[i]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            arrSplit[i] = arrSplit[i].Trim();
                            byte[] codes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(arrSplit[i].ToCharArray(), 0, 1);
                            if (codes[0] > 47 && codes[0] < 58 || codes[0] > 64 && codes[0] < 91 || codes[0] > 96 && codes[0] < 123)//EDIT 3.1 reverse just hebrew words                              
                            {
                                str += arrSplit[i].Trim();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                str += Reverse(arrSplit[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return str;
    }
        static public string Reverse(string str)
        {
            char[] strArray = str.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(strArray);
            return new string(strArray);
        }
```

Comment: very big shkiyech and toda!

Answer (score -1):

```
public static string Reverse(string t)
    {
        char[] charArray = t.ToCharArray();
        string a = "";
        int last = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= charArray.Length-1; i++)
        {

            if (!IsHebrew(charArray[i]))
            {
                List<char> temp = new List<char>();

                for (; last < i; last++)
                {
                    int k = 0;
                    temp.Insert(0,charArray[last]);
                }

                foreach(char g in temp)
                {
                    a += g.ToString();
                }
                a += charArray[i];
                last += 1;
            }
        }

        return a;
    }
    private const char FirstHebChar = (char)1488; //א
    private const char LastHebChar = (char)1514; //ת
    private static bool IsHebrew(char c)
    {
        return c >= FirstHebChar && c <= LastHebChar;
    }
```

Comment: why call Clear() right after making new List? Also last += 1 can be written as ++last or last++

Comment: fix the clear tnx ,love the +=1 and will keep to use it tnx anyway